# bash xargs for loop having issues with variables and arguments

Tags: linux, bash, awk, xargs

I have a while loop that calls on xargs to name files based on part of the output.

```
do
$CLIPATH/show attributes attr=0x1006e attr=0x3b1090d attr=0x3b10944 attr=0x3b1093e attr=0x3b10943 attr=0x100c5 attr=0x100ad mh=${line} > /mnt/path/temp
cat /mnt/path/file2 | grep 'x1006e' | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'for arg do [[ -d /mnt/path"$arg" ]] || mkdir /mnt/path/"$arg"; cp /mnt/path/temp /mnt/path/"$arg"/$(eval "date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_"")"$arg".txt; cat /mnt/path/"$arg"/$(eval "date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_"")"$arg".txt | grep '0x1006e' | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' > /mnt/path/"$arg"/$(eval "date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_"")"$arg"_name.txt ; done' _
done
```

I am having three issues:

The first is that the last awk portion *; cat /mnt/path/"$arg"/$(eval "date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_"")"$arg".txt | grep '0x1006e' | **awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "*** is failing because it needs to be formatted differently within the xargs loop to run properly I think.

The second issue is that I can't seem to call upon variables that exist outside of the for loop without errors. For example */mnt/path/* has a variable earlier in the script, but it fails to be called upon so I am just writing the full path each time.

The third issue is that I can't format the separated arguments from the for loop to look clean with carriage returns without them failing. I'd like it to look like something like this:

```
do
$CLIPATH/show attributes attr=0x1006e attr=0x3b1090d attr=0x3b10944 attr=0x3b1093e attr=0x3b10943 attr=0x100c5 attr=0x100ad mh=${line} > /mnt/path/temp
cat /mnt/path/file2 | grep 'x1006e' | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'for arg do [[ -d /mnt/path"$arg" ]] || mkdir /mnt/path/"$arg";

cp /mnt/path/temp /mnt/path/"$arg"/$(eval "date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_"")"$arg".txt;

cat /mnt/path/"$arg"/$(eval "date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_"")"$arg".txt | grep '0x1006e' | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' > /mnt/path/"$arg"/$(eval "date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_"")"$arg"_name.txt;
done' _
done
```

I am not the best scripter, so I imagine a lot of this could be written better. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `"$arg"`? Why do you use `xargs` and not a normal loop?

Answer (score 0):

Do not put super long code in one line. Encapsulate code in functions, use `export -f` and `export` and `declare -f` and `declare -p` to transfer functions and variables to separate shells. Write *clear* code. Check your scripts with shellcheck. Do not use eval.

In this case, just write a normal loop.

```
cat /mnt/path/file2 |
grep 'x1006e' |
awk '{print $3}' |
while IFS= read -r arg; do
     mkdir -p /mnt/path/"$arg"
     cp /mnt/path/temp "/mnt/path/$arg/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_)$arg".txt
     cat "/mnt/path/$arg/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_)$arg.txt" |
        grep '0x1006e' |
        awk '{
            s = ""
            for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "
            print s
        }' > "/mnt/path/$arg/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H_)$arg_name.txt";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `xargs` here; you are using shell to run `xargs` to pass a bunch of (subdirectory) names to *another* shell which then processes them individually, while you could just have the original shell process them and it would be a lot clearer (and even slightly more efficient). Also when using `awk` you don't need `grep` or `cat` with rare exceptions not present here. And you can only put bash commands in `do` ... `done` if they are the body of loop which you don't have and didn't ask for.

```
dir=/mnt/path # demonstrate this also since you asked about it
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_) # put this in a variable to allow reuse
$CLIPATH/show attributes attr=0x1006e attr=0x3b1090d attr=0x3b10944 attr=0x3b1093e attr=0x3b10943 attr=0x100c5 attr=0x100ad mh=${line} > "$dir"/temp
awk <"$dir"/file2 '/x1006e/{print $3}' | while read -r arg; do
  [[ -d "$dir$arg" ]] || mkdir "$dir$arg"
  cp "$dir/temp" "$dir/$arg/$now$arg".txt
  awk <"$dir/$arg/$now$arg".txt '/0x1006e/{ s = ""; for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' >"$dir/$arg/$now$arg"_name.txt
done
```

Notes:

- did you really mean to put the output of `$CLIPATH/show` in `$dir/temp` but then process the 'arg' values (subdirectory names) from `$dir/file2`? Or should these be the same?
- in general if a variable value can contain whitespace or 'pattern' (aka wildcard or glob) characters `?*[` you need to enclose any reference to it in doublequotes `"...$var..."` to avoid problems. In your case `dir=/mnt/path` does not contain any such characters so I don't really need the `"` but I used them to follow good practice. Also, in two specific places not applicable here (assignment values and herestrings) putting `$var` in `"` isn't needed, but many people still do so for consistency.
- instead of the loop over 3..NF in awk, you *could* use the following trick:

  ```
    awk <input '/0x1006e/{$1=$2=""; print substr($0,3)}' >output
  ```

  but if you do anyone who has to read or maintain your code may attack you with blunt heavy objects.